# JQuery: accessing LI nodes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML

```
<ul id="listing">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

How can I access the 2nd `LI` inner text?

Can I do

```
$("#listing li").[1].text()
```

If not, what is the sytax?

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#listing li:eq(1)").text();
```

More about the Index Selector at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index

Answer (score 4):

close

```
$("#listing li").eq(1).text()
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq

Comment: What you linked too show the following syntax -> $("#listing li:eq(1)").text();
Does your syntax work (is supported). Your syntax makes more sense to me

Comment: did you read the other guys link? my link has  $("div").eq(2).addClass("blue");

Comment: Does one version perform better than another?

Comment: okay this is promising... http://www.spadgos.com/?p=51

seems like the eq() method is around five times faster than :eq() granted, it probably doesn't matter at all in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [eq selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index) in jquery